# Populate table with ng-repeat and check matching header data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have array of years which I use to populate table header row and I have an object that I use to populate the table.
I need to populate the correct year data under the corresponding year header, so I'd need to check if the year(Y) in the object corresponds to the year in the header array, if not then I'd need to add an empty cell. The object is sorted by year. What would be the best way to do that?
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/soLtcbam/#&togetherjs=ooRHs8DV5C)

CONTROLLER

```
 var app = angular.module("testModule", []);
 app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
 $scope.headerYears = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020];

$scope.rows = [{
  "Name": "Name1",
  "Col": [{
    "Y": 2013,
    "M": 25711
  }, {
    "Y": 2014,
    "M": 26095
  }, {
    "Y": 2015,
    "M": 23641
  }, {
    "Y": 2016,
    "M": 22224
  }, {
    "Y": 2017,
    "M": 21968
  }, {
    "Y": 2018,
    "M": 23820
  }, {
    "Y": 2019,
    "M": 26673
  }, {
    "Y": 2020,
    "M": 29329.5
  }]
}, {
  "Name": "Name2",
  "Col": [{
    "Y": 2013,
    "M": 83
  }, {
    "Y": 2014,
    "M": 461
  }, {
    "Y": 2015,
    "M": 1067
  }, {
    "Y": 2016,
    "M": 1120
  }, {
    "Y": 2017,
    "M": 1050
  }, {
    "Y": 2018,
    "M": 600
  }, {
    "Y": 2019,
    "M": 475
  }, {
    "Y": 2020,
    "M": 481
  }]
}, {
  "Name": "Name3",
  "Col": [{
    "Y": 2013,
    "M": 25794
  }, {
    "Y": 2014,
    "M": 26556
  }, {
    "Y": 2015,
    "M": 24708
  }, {
    "Y": 2016,
    "M": 23424
  }, {
    "Y": 2017,
    "M": 23297
  }, {
    "Y": 2018,
    "M": 24412.5
  }, {
    "Y": 2019,
    "M": 27090.5
  }, {
    "Y": 2020,
    "M": 29754.5
  }]
 }]
});
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" data-ng-app="testModule" data-ng-controller="testController">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="i in headerYears">{{i}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="item in row.Col">{{item.M}}{{item.Y}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: According to me you should write your application logic code like syncing all `rows Col` data according to `headerYears`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do an ng-if in the DOM

```
<table border="1" data-ng-app="testModule" data-ng-controller="testController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="i in headerYears">{{i}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td ng-repeat="i in headerYears" >{{i}}  
      <span ng-repeat="row in rows"></span> 
      <span ng-repeat="item in row.Col">{{item.Y}} </span>
      </td>     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: you can add an NG-IF to the span like span ng-if="item.Y==i" and another span ng-if="item.Y != i"

Comment: This is the simplest and allows me to modify the output after. I'm not sure what would be the downfall to use this approach..

Answer (score 0):

Since row.col's length can be smaller,greater or equals to the headerYears length you have to make sure that your table has consistency on the columns.

This means for each row, you have to reapeat over headerYears to create the same column size.

Take a look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ozSSwrI3XPFm1WgqJBTQ) i created which may give you the solution.

Also it is a good idea to create a new array of objects that are bound to the years provided in the controller and then ng-repeat to this new array.

Imho this will give a cleaner DOM and can be maintained easier.

I added a filter in order to read over columns data and return the one that suits each situation.

```
 app.filter('testFilter', function() {
    return function(col, header) {
       if (!col ){
        return "Empty";
       } 
       if (!header){
        return "Empty"; 
       }


       var returnVal="Empty Item";
       angular.forEach(col, function(colItem){
         if(header===colItem.Y) {
            returnVal = colItem.M+" "+colItem.Y;
        }
       });

    return returnVal;

   }
});
```

Also i changed the DOM and now it looks somehting like the following

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="i in headerYears">
         {{row.Col | testFilter:i }}
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This seems to be the most suitable answer so far. Yet, if I have more properties in colItem that I want to display in <td> and I'd like to style them differently and perhaps turn them on off then I would need something like <td><span>colItem.M</span><span ng-show="show">colItem.Y</span></td> ... if I return the entire object from the filter e.g. returnVal=colItem; How can I access it in DOM? I hope my question makes sense..

Comment: yes your question has sense. Since you want to have the control of customizing the DOM inside the <td> tags, if i were in your shoes i would make a directive responsiple for that job with isolated scope on the whole object and use it like shown in the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vLCmcHV475BmBDbSeA38?p=preview) You can always use the templateUrl functionality of the directive so you can have a clear view of what is going on. This way you can also add some functionality per cell like CRUD opperations

Answer (score 0):

This works well and is better than building a custom filter for every value you want to display (i.e. you can put any HTML you'd like inside the TD and just use {{item.myProperty}} like normal).  Enjoy!

It puts all of your data into a format that matches the headers, which lets JS do what it does best, and then gives clean data to Angular.  Hope that helps!

```
//START OF GOOD CODE
$scope.rows = null;

(function(){
  var raw = [{ /** this is all your current "rows" data, just moved**/ }];

  var bucketize = function(col) {
      var data = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.headerYears.length; i++) {
          data.push({}); //initialize to match headerYears setup
          for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
              if (col[j].Y == $scope.headerYears[i]) {
                  data[i] = col[j]; //replace initialized value with real data
              }
          }
      }
      return data;
  };

  var rows = new Array();

  for (var x = 0; x < raw.length; x++) {
    var row = raw[x];
    row.Col = bucketize(row.Col); //sort data and format it for our desired HTML        
    rows.push(row);
  }

  $scope.rows = rows; //give the scrubbed data to Angular
})();
//END OF GOOD CODE
```

--EDIT--

The following creates an infinite digest loop because it returns a new Array() on each call to the bucketize() function. Instead, scrub the data before giving it to Angular (see above).  You can do this in an AJAX success handler, or even with an SEAF like I did above.

```
//NOTE THIS IS BAD, DUE TO INFINITE LOOP CAUSED BY "new Array();"
...
<td ng-repeat="item in bucketize(row.Col)">{{item.Y}}</td>
...
$scope.bucketize = function(col) {
    var data = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.headerYears.length; i++) {
        data.push({}); //initialize to match headerYears setup
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            if (col[j].Y == $scope.headerYears[i]) {
                data[i] = col[j]; //replace initialized value with real data
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
};
//END OF BAD CODE
```

- Kieron

Comment: I'd even just build the data inside the first for() loop with a "data = new Array(); ... for... data.push({}); ..." just to ensure that it always exactly matches the headers if they're variable... but anyway.  Like I said, hope that helps!

Comment: It does work but unfortunately returns https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig error in browser.

Comment: Good catch!  I didn't watch the console, just the HTML output.  This happens because each iteration returned a new object called "data" which then triggers a whole new set of digests.  I updated the code to work outside of Angular.  I still highly recommend this approach -- it's basically doing the same thing as the answer you accepted, but it's relying on JS to make the JS data right -- and relying on Angular to make the HTML match the JS data -- which is exactly what each is supposed to do.